# Synchronized, notify e wait - Client Servidor

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am developing an application to send messages between client and server, however the server class have some functions such as those below. Someone could help me by example in these functions where i put the wait and notify functions and these functions are synchronized or not? I know for example that when I move into my HashMap utilizadores (shared resource) so I have to use notifys not know is where. Supposedly the functions of writing messages should not be in wait when there is no new messages?

Thank you for your help!

```
synchronized void getMessage(message){
while(!newMessages)
wait();
add(new Message());
notifyAll();
}
```

---

```
 public class SocketServidor extends Thread{
 private ServerSocket servidorSocket;
 private Socket socket;
 private static final int PORTA = 8080;

//hashmap: serve para enquanto cliente ir buscar as mensagens que lhe pertencem ao servidor; String nome cliente e respectiva mensagem
private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> utilizadores = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();  


public SocketServidor(){
try {
    servidorSocket = new ServerSocket(PORTA);               

    System.out.println("Lançou ServerSocket: " + PORTA);
    System.out.println("A aguardar conexão do cliente...");

    while(true){                                            

        socket = servidorSocket.accept();                   

        new Thread(new ListennerSocket(socket)).start();    
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
}


private class ListennerSocket implements Runnable {
private ObjectOutputStream output;                          
private ObjectInputStream input;                        

public ListennerSocket(Socket socket) {
    try {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Nova conexão com o cliente " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

    Mensagem mensagem = null;

    try {
        while((mensagem = (Mensagem) input.readObject() )!= null){                              Accao accao = mensagem.getAccao();                                  
            if(accao.equals(Accao.ONLINE)){
                boolean estaConectado = conectar(mensagem, output);
                if(estaConectado){
                    utilizadores.put(mensagem.getNomeClienteEnviaMensagem(),output);
                    adicionarListaContactosOnline();
                }
            }else if(accao.equals(Accao.OFFLINE)){
                sair(mensagem, output);
                System.out.println(mensagem.getNomeClienteEnviaMensagem() + " deixou a aplicacao QuequeAPP");
                return;                         
            }else if(accao.equals(Accao.ENVIAR_UM)){
                enviar_para_um(mensagem);
            }else if(accao.equals(Accao.ENVIAR_TODOS)){
                enviar_para_todos(mensagem);
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        sair(mensagem, output);
        adicionarListaContactosOnline();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private boolean conectar(Mensagem mensagem, ObjectOutputStream output){         
    if(utilizadores.size() == 0){   
        mensagem.setMensagem("Conectado!");
        enviar(mensagem, output);
        return true;
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> i : utilizadores.entrySet()){
        if(i.getKey().equals(mensagem.getNomeClienteEnviaMensagem())){
            mensagem.setMensagem("Não conectado!");
            enviar(mensagem, output);                                           
            return false;
        }else{
            mensagem.setMensagem("Conectado!");
            enviar(mensagem, output);
            return true;                                                        
        }
    }
    return false;                                                               
}


private void enviar(Mensagem mensagem, ObjectOutputStream output){              
    try {
        output.writeObject(mensagem);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void sair(Mensagem mensagem, ObjectOutputStream output){                

    utilizadores.remove(mensagem.getNomeClienteEnviaMensagem());

    mensagem.setMensagem("Offline");

    mensagem.setAccao(Accao.ENVIAR_UM);

    enviar_para_todos(mensagem);
}




private void enviar_para_um(Mensagem mensagem){
    for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
        if(mapa.getKey().equals(mensagem.getNomeClienteReceptorMensagem())) {       
            try {
                mapa.getValue().writeObject(mensagem);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


private void enviar_para_todos(Mensagem mensagem) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
        if(!mapa.getKey().equals(mensagem.getNomeClienteEnviaMensagem())){
            mensagem.setAccao(Accao.ENVIAR_UM);
            try {
                mapa.getValue().writeObject(mensagem);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


private void adicionarListaContactosOnline(){
    Set<String> listaContactosOnline = new HashSet<String>();

    for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
        listaContactosOnline.add(mapa.getKey());
    }

    Mensagem mensagem = new Mensagem();
    mensagem.setAccao(Accao.CONTACTOS_ONLINE);
    mensagem.setContactosOnline(listaContactosOnline);                  

    for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
        mensagem.setNomeClienteEnviaMensagem(mapa.getKey());
        try {
            System.out.println("Contacto Online: " + mapa.getKey());                
            mapa.getValue().writeObject(mensagem);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to synchronize every time you read from, put, or iterate on the map. Or you need to use a concurrent map (which would be easier, safer and faster). But I see no reason why you would need to wait() or notify(). Why do you think so?

Comment: thanks for the answer! yes i understand the synchronize. the wait() and the notify() are questions from the work that im developing. i will need to do something like the functions that e add in the post

Comment: @JBNizet (forgot to identify)